# listView with editText - TextWatcher reloading view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext, textwatcher

I've coded a `ListView` with some `TextView` and an `EditText`. This one has a `TextWatcher` which in `afterTextChange()` method add an instance to a sigleton class. All it's ok, but when I'm scrolling the `ListView` and I'm modifying value of an `EditText`, `ListView` is reloaded and scroll bar is returned on top.
It's a normal feedback or I can control this behavior?

**PART OF TEXTWATCHER**

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){ 
            if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString())!=0){

                HashMap<Products, Integer> into=new HashMap<Products,Integer>();
                Products pr = new Products();
                into = cart.getProdotti();
                pr.set_id(Integer.parseInt(pro.get("id").toString()));
                pr.setPrezzo(Double.parseDouble(pro.get("prezzo").toString()));
                pr.setNome(pro.get("nome").toString());
                boolean flag = false;
                if(!into.isEmpty()){
                    Iterator<Products> iter = into.keySet().iterator();
                    while(iter.hasNext()){
                        if(pr.get_id()==iter.next().get_id()){
                            into.put(pr, Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                            cart.setProdotti(into);
                            flag = true;
                        }                       
                    }
                    if(flag==false){
                        into.put(pr, Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                        cart.setProdotti(into);
                    }
                }else{
                    into.put(pr, Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                    cart.setProdotti(into);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

GETVIEW of ADAPTER

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);

        TextView nome = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.nomeProdotto); // title
        TextView descrizione = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.descrizioneProdotto); // artist name
        TextView prezzo = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.prezzoProdotto); // duration
        //ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
        final EditText quantity = (EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.quantity);


        product = products.get(position);


        nome.setText(product.get("nome"));
        descrizione.setText(product.get("descrizione"));
        prezzo.setText("€"+product.get("prezzo"));
        quantity.setText("0");
        quantity.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(products.get(position)));
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you creating your listview? When scrolling, the listview will destroy the non shown elements and recreate them again when you scroll back.

Comment: posting code can help users to suggest any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal behavior. You need to store the first visible index and set it to it when the listview is reloaded.

You need to use getFirstVisiblePosition() before reloading to find the index and after reloading use setSelection(position) to set it the older view position.

Comment: but where listview is reloaded? I don't invoke any reloading!!

Answer (score 0):

are you using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to reload your ListView? if you use this you won't face such problem..